# Angular-Translate Variable Replacement in Title Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm working on an AngularJS application with Angular-Translate 2.6.1. I have a span with a title attribute that will be translated, but it needs to display a variable as well.

```
<span title={{'translationID'|translate:'{username:"Value"}'}}>...</span>
```

I've tried replacing "Value" with {{Value}}, with and without quotes. Value is defined in the scope, and I can access it with {{Value}} outside of a filter.

The only luck I've had so far with variable replacement in Angular-Translate is using the translate directive

(e.g. `<span translate="translationID" translate-value-username="{{Value}}">...</span>`),

but that doesn't seem to be an option here. Is variable replacement in a filter like this possible, or do I need to find another solution?

EDIT:
For readability, here is the solution:

```
<span title="{{'translationID'|translate:{username:Value} }}">...</span>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<span title="{{'translationID'|translate:{username:Value} }}">...</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI, that syntax works outside of a tag, but it needs double-quotes around it for it to work as a title.

Comment: Hello miensol, i also facing some translation problem my heading are bellow . at a time when i will switch language rest of all translation id throw translating. but not this line  <ion-slide ion-slide-tab-label="{{'hpgT3' | translate }}" > but its working but when i refresh my page.